# Post apocalyptic American biker novel called Hardrider

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic, dystopia

I'm looking for a hard copy or ecopy  of a book I bought in florida sometime in the early 90s. It was about a boy from a nomadic biker gang who survived the massacre of the gang and was taken into care by the city state that massacred the gang. 
The book follows him from orphanage to adoption through to the military and finally a plains renegade.

The character's name was Tristan Tomlinson/ Burning Skull.

Answer (score 4):

**Stormrider 1** (Post-Nuke Action, No 1) by Robert Baron. 1992.

Upholding his vision of freedom and democracy, maverick biker Tristan Hardrider escapes from the school that was brainwashing him and takes to the nuclear-ravaged American frontier to become Stormrider--legendary leader of the High Free Folk.

A quote from Stormrider 2:

Unlike his father, Tristan had no problem with cunning and misdirection. He prided himself, though, on knowing when you had to face something squarely. He reckoned this was one of those times. "I'll set the Plains alight with the Burning Skull ..."

[https://www.amazon.com/Stormrider-Post-Nuke-Action-Robert-Baron/dp/0515108286](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0515108286)